# How to pick top value from tie-break group using Unix sort

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, unix, awk

I have the following text file:

```
$ cat myfile.txt
foo,a,10
bar,c,33
foo,b,50
bar,a,9
foo,a,20
bar,b,20
```

What I want to do is to sort by 2nd column and 3rd (numeric descending) and finally pick the top of each 2nd column group, resulting in

```
foo,a,20
foo,b,50
bar,c,33
```

I'm stuck with this:

```
$ sort -t"," -k2 -k3r   test.txt
foo,a,10
foo,a,20
bar,a,9
bar,b,20
foo,b,50
bar,c,33
```

Whats the right way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `sort` command is close. `-k` actually takes a range of fields, so your `-k2` is being interpreted as "sort on everything from the second field to the end of the line," and it's ignoring the `-k3` entirely. You have to be explicit about where the ranges start and end. You also want to sort on the third numerically.

Here's all that put together:

```
$ sort -t, -k2,2 -k3,3nr myfile.txt
foo,a,20
foo,a,10
bar,a,9
foo,b,50
bar,b,20
bar,c,33
```

Now you want to pick the first line of each group, based on the second field. Although `sort` has the ability to dedup a stream, it's not smart enough to handle complex scenarios like this. Fortunately, we have awk:

```
$ sort -t, -k2,2 -k3,3nr myfile.txt | awk -F, 'x != $2 { print; x = $2 }'
foo,a,20
foo,b,50
bar,c,33
```

Comment: A deleted answer suggested `!unique[$2]++` as the `awk` script, which also seems to work: `sort -t, -k2,2 -k3,3nr myfile.txt | awk -F, '!unique[$2]++'`. Not sure whether that's preferable to your solution, but it's fewer characters ;)

Comment: Either awk script is fine! Whichever you find easier to remember for future uses. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's pure `awk` method to do that,

```
 awk -F, '{split(a[$2],b,",");if(b[3]<$3)a[$2]=$0}END{for(i in a)print [i]}' myfile.txt
```

Brief explanation,

- `split(a[$2],b,",")`: split each record separated by ',', and save each field to array b.
- `if(b[3]<$3)a[$2]=$0`: compare b[3] and $3 to determine if a[$2] needs to be updated
- Print all content in array a in the last.

Answer (score -1):

awk smauk

PURE BASH!!

```
regex=',(.+),'
var="xx"
for line in $(sort -t, -k2,2 -k3,3nr myfile.txt); do
  if [[ $line =~ $regex ]]; then
    bashrematch=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    if [[ "$var" != "$bashrematch" ]]; then
      var=$bashrematch
      echo $line
    fi
  fi
done
foo,a,20
foo,b,50
bar,c,33
```

just to compress and shrink the code a bit

```
r=',(.+),'; v=""; for l in $(sort -t, -k2,2 -k3,3nr myfile.txt); do [[ $l =~ $r ]] && b=${BASH_REMATCH[1]} && [ "$v" != "$b" ] && v=$b && echo $l; done
foo,a,20
foo,b,50
bar,c,33
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit formatting the bash, @dimo414, the post was made in one line to conform with the style of the question, and the other answers.  Also you changed a line that was correct, to another, also correct based on your preference.  I'm fine either way, this was meant as an exercise to learn how to use bash to solve the problem.  =)